# Is there a Google Input tools alternative for Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, language-support, input-language, input-method

For typing non-English languages, the ubuntu keyboard does not provide auto suggestions like Google Input tools. There is only the phonetic typing option. Is there a good alternative which is as powerful as Google Input tools for Ubuntu.

Comment: Do you want smart suggestions?

Comment: Changed smart to auto to reflect the question accurately. I am not aware of any Ubuntu keyboard that throws in suggestions like Google Input tools

Answer (score 1):

For Indic languages there is an offline tool: https://varnamproject.com/